# Import image into Component template, from an URL that is being passed as a property of the Component [Vue + Vite]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have an image in a Component's template, of which I want to set its 'src' from a property.
I tried doing it like this at first:

**Gallery View, from where the Component is called multiple times**

```html
<script setup>
import ProjectPreview from "../components/ProjectPreview.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <ProjectPreview cover="../assets/img/projects/summary/cover.jpg" title="Summary (Illustration)"
      desc="Personal work" url="https://example.com" />
    <ProjectPreview cover="@/assets/img/projects/axes/cover.jpg" title="Axes (Concept Art)"
      desc="Prop design"
      url="https://example.com" />
    <ProjectPreview cover="@/assets/img/projects/summary/cover.jpg" title="Summary (Illustration)"
      desc="Personal work" url="https://example.com" />
    <ProjectPreview cover="@/assets/img/projects/summary/cover.jpg" title="Summary (Illustration)"
      desc="Personal work" url="https://example.com" />
  </main>
</template>
```

**Component (ProjectPreview)**

```html
<script setup>
defineProps({
    cover: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="card mx-1" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img :src="cover" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-primary">{{title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{desc}}</p>
            <a href="{{url}}" class="btn btn-danger">See full project</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Vite config**

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

const path = require("path");

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
      "~bootstrap": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap"),
    },
  },
});
```

But it does not work, and it seems like the URL is not being well resolved (the '@' symbol is not being resolved at all).

I tried looking at the docs and searching for similar errors but do not understand where the problem could be. I also could not find examples where the image was being loaded from a property of the Component.

---

#### Final code after @Yitz 's answer.

**View**

```html
<script setup>
import ProjectPreview from "../components/ProjectPreview.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <ProjectPreview cover="projects/summary/cover.jpg" title="Summary (Illustration)"
      desc="Personal work" url="https://example.com" />
    <ProjectPreview cover="projects/axes/cover.jpg" title="Axes (Concept Art)"
      desc="Prop design"
      url="https://example.com" />
  </main>
</template>
```

**Component**

```html
<script setup>
defineProps({
    cover: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

function getUrl(file) {
    return new URL(`/src/assets/img/${file}`, import.meta.url).href;
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="card mx-1" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img :src="getUrl(cover)" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-primary">{{title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{desc}}</p>
            <a href="{{url}}" class="btn btn-danger">See full project</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
cover="projects/summary/cover.jpg"
```

Then have a function

```
getUrl(file) {
    return new URL(`/src/assets/img/${file}`, import.meta.url).href;
}
```

in your script.

Then use it like

```
 <img :src="getUrl(cover)" .../>
```

You don't need the `@`, Vite should take care of the proper location for you.

Comment: Hi Yitz, thank you for your help.
I created the function getUrl in the methods object of the Component, I assumed that was the way. But when calling the function, I get the error "_ctx.getUrl is not a function". Should I define it differently?

Comment: In the component where you're using the :src attribute? Also make sure it's capitalised the same. I didn't do that in my answer so correcting it now.

Comment: You shouldn't need a methods object if you're using script setup. Just put the method  declaration after your defineProps call.

Comment: Yes, I think everything is capitalised correctly and its in the same component! I updated my question to add the Component code, if it is of any help. I do not know if the structure is correct. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh okay! I edited it and removed the script setup, but I will try it that way now.

Comment: In the code you posted you're calling `getURL` with capitals?

Comment: Oh ok I just saw it. I did not get what you meant at first, I thought you just meant the first "U" orz. Thank you and sorry!

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you! I do not understand what you meant when you said I could still leave the `@` though, do you mean in the `return new URL(...)` code?

Comment: I meant leave it out, don't use it. Glad it works now!